# How to send only "update" data from mysql to mobile device by PHP webservices?

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios, web-services

I wonder how to send only "update" data to mobile device. Assume that I build mobile app for iOS and Android that uses PHP webservices to get data. When we start application first time it get all data form mysql database using json. But when we start it second time I don't want to delete old data on my mobile device and fetch all data one more time. I would prefer only to download "update" using php webservices from my database. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a timestamp column in your database so that you're only pulling back data that has been updated since the last time you made a request?

Comment: That's why cache and cookies were invented in browser..

Comment: You can use sqlite for saving the downloaded data and create a [SharedPreference] flag to indicate if the app is already downloaded the data.
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)